# remove js code from page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added js code dynamically:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var js = document.createElement("script");

js.type = "text/javascript";
js.id ="jsChange";
js.src = "myRoute.js";

head.appendChild(js);
```

It works fine, the problem is when I try to remove, I can get the way.

```
$('#jsChange').remove() //Doesnt work
```

I also try to add a div in head and put the js inside:

```
$('#divToJS').append(js);
```

and:

```
$('#divToJS').empty(); // doesnt work
```

How can I do it?

Comment: `DiV` elements don't belong in the `HEAD`. Why are you trying to remove code that you just added dynamically? And, `.remove` is a method, so you'd need to write it as `.remove()`

Comment: are you sure you are not trying to remove the dynamically added code before you added it? it's not clear from what you provided. A fiddle would go a long way too

Answer (score 2):

Your empty and remove both need () on the call.
E.G.

`$('#jsChange').remove` to `$('#jsChange').remove();`

`$('#divToJS').empty` to `$('#divToJS').empty();`

Unless i've misread the question, this should solve your issue.

Comment: I would recommend maybe dynamically adding a script tag with a unique id that you can empty and add code to.

Comment: I think that would allow you to do what you want to without much issue.

Comment: thats what i do with js.id ="jsChange";